# Fire a trigger after the update of specific columns in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers

In MySQL, I want to fire a trigger *after the update* of specific columns.

I know how to do it in Oracle and DB2:

```
CREATE  TRIGGER  myTrigger
AFTER UPDATE of myColumn1,myColumn2 ... ON myTable
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
....
END
```

How to do that with MySQL?

Answer (score 74, accepted):

You can't trigger on a particular column update in SQL. It is applied on a row.

You can put your condition for columm in your trigger with an `IF` statement, as below:

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER myTrigger AFTER UPDATE ON myTable
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
   IF !(NEW.column1 <=> OLD.column1) THEN
      --type your statements here
   END IF;
END;//
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: It's worth to mention that `<>` won't work with `NULL`s. You should either use null-safe equality operator `<=>` or additionally check for  `NULL`s.

Comment: Using <=> is causing a problem for me, if NEW.column1 = OLD.column1  then it still fires the statement written in if clause.

Comment: According to MySQL documentation there is no `!<=>` operator so you can use `!(NEW.columnName <=> OLD.columnName)` instead to determine if new value is different from the old one.

Answer (score 7):

You can't specify only to fire on specific column changes. But for a record change on a table you can do

```
delimiter |
CREATE  TRIGGER  myTrigger AFTER UPDATE ON myTable
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
   ...
END
|
delimiter ;
```

In your trigger you can refer to old and new content of a column like this

```
if NEW.column1 <> OLD.column1 ...
```

Answer (score 6):

As a solution, I did like that:

```
CREATE  TRIGGER  myTrigger
AFTER UPDATE  ON myTable
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
IF NEW.myColumn1 <> OLD.myColumn1 || NEW.myColumn2 <> OLD.myColumn2
then

.....

END IF
END
```