# MySQL Trigger Update based on value

Tags: mysql, events, triggers

So I have this Multiple tables with contacts

```
Contact_1
-----------------------------
| id | name | contact_number |
-----------------------------
| 1  | Ben | 12345          |
------------------------------
| 2  | John | 1325           |
------------------------------

contact_2
-----------------------------
| id | name | contact_number |
-----------------------------
| 1  | Ben | 12345          |
------------------------------
| 2  | John | 1325           |
------------------------------
contact_3
-----------------------------
| id | name | contact_number |
-----------------------------
| 1  | Ben | 12345          |
------------------------------
| 2  | John | 1325           |
------------------------------
```

and I have made already a trigger event.

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER update_contact AFTER UPDATE ON contact_1 FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    UPDATE contact_2 SET contact_number = NEW.contact_number WHERE pm_id = NEW.pm_id;
    UPDATE contact_3 SET contact_number = NEW.contact_number WHERE pm_id = NEW.pm_id;
END; $$
DELIMITER;
```

My question is how can I trigger this event only if contact_number is updated.
If name is updated the event should NOT run. TIA. The query must be in MySQL I think other SQL has a different syntax of handling this challenge.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [fire a trigger after the update of specific columns in mysql](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19152974/fire-a-trigger-after-the-update-of-specific-columns-in-mysql)

Comment: why you want to use a trigger? your table structure is not normalized, can you normalize it?

Comment: @Sandy Pabilonia - Table structure not looks good. Please tell me why you are using more than one table for storing contacts?

Comment: I can't normalize it. The applications using it was design to store data in a denormalize manner.

Comment: @FathahRehmanP  Because before different contacts were being used by different applications. We are now on the of creating just one contact table. The trigger is just a temporary solution for synching the different contact tables.

Comment: @SandyPabilonia - is this problem solved?

Comment: @FathahRehmanP we are now on the process of making new contact list database schema. Thanks Fathah..