# How to loop an array in MySQL

Tags: mysql, arrays, loops, triggers

[fire a trigger after the update of specific columns in mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19152974/fire-a-trigger-after-the-update-of-specific-columns-in-mysql)

This question is not helping me as it ***REQUIRES MULTIPLE IF CONDITION***.

---

Essentially I want to create a trigger to log all changes inside table. ***I don't want to write it in multiple if condition as it repeats code***. I know how to handle it in JavaScript as follows:

```
[
    'column1',
    'column2',
    'column3',
    'column4',
    'column5',
    'column6'
].forEach(function(column) {
    if (newEntity[column] != oldEntity[column]) {
        INSERT(newEntity.id, column, newEntity[column], oldEntity[column], NOW())
    }
});
```

How to write it in MySQL?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [fire a trigger after the update of specific columns in mysql](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19152974/fire-a-trigger-after-the-update-of-specific-columns-in-mysql)

Comment: Why might a var appear in multiple columns?

Comment: Updating sorry.

Comment: do you have a column with 'date_added' and another with 'date_updated'?

Comment: No. I need to track with entity changed and which column of it changed from what to what

Comment: with those columns created you can easily create a procedure just by simply running a simple query

Comment: Can you show me how? I do have a updated_at and created_at in my entity table

Comment: can you update your message with an image of the DB table? That would make it easier for me

Answer (score 0):

```
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS t_afterupdate_on_tab1;
```

CREATE TRIGGER t_afterupdate_on_tab1 
AFTER UPDATE ON tab1
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
     insert into tab2(new_id,old_value,new_value) values(old.id,old.value,new.value);
END;