# MYSQL - How to create a trigger after an UPDATE in a table, to increment +1 the value of a column from another table?

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers

These are my tables:

I'm creating the trigger after i update this table:

*Table 'avisos':*

```
idAvisos | retirado 
---------------------
   1     |    0 
   2     |    1
```

*Table 'recolectores':*

```
idRecolector | num_avisos_retirados
-----------------------------------
      1      |         0 
      2      |         4
```

So what i want to do is, after i update the table avisos to set "retirado" to true (1), i want to sum +1 to the column "num_avisos_retirados" of the recolectores table.

Example: when idAvisos (1) changes "retirado" to 1, the idRecolector (1) will have to change the num_avisos_retirados to 1.

Here's what i've done so far:

```
CREATE TRIGGER NumAvisosRecolectados_AU #after update
AFTER UPDATE ON avisos.retirado
    IF (NEW.retirado = 1) THEN
        UPDATE recolectores
        SET recolectores.num_avisos_recolectados = recolectores.num_avisos_recolectados + 1
    END IF;
```

Also, what i don't understand is if i have to use a WHERE clause, to actually hit the right idRecolector of the "recolectores" table. My teacher gave us an example similar to this, but she didn't use a WHERE clause to check the right ID. Does it join the right table automatically?

When i run that sql statement i get this error:

> Wrong syntax near'IF (NEW.retirado = 1) THEN
> UPDATE recolectores
> SET recolectore' en la linea 3

**UPDATE**

After reading this: [Fire a trigger after the update of specific columns in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19152974/fire-a-trigger-after-the-update-of-specific-columns-in-mysql)

I now changed my statement, because i cant use UPDATE ON avisos.retirado, instead i have to use FOR EACH ROW and an IF statement to check for a specific column change. I also added a WHERE clause to actually hit the right id that i want to update, as suggested by @nbk

Here's the code now:

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER NumAvisosRecolectados_AU #after update
AFTER UPDATE ON avisos
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    IF (NEW.retirado = 1) THEN
        BEGIN
            UPDATE recolectores
            SET recolectores.num_avisos_recolectados = recolectores.num_avisos_recolectados + 1
            WHERE reservas.FK_IDavisos = avisos.ID_avisos
            AND reservas.FK_IDrecolector = recolectores.ID_recolector
        END
    END IF;
END; //
DELIMITER ;
```

But i'm still getting a syntax error:

> #1064 - Wrong syntax near 'END
> END IF;

Comment: You could have tested this in less than half the time it took you to write this SO question...

Comment: @jarlh i forgot to add the error, i already tested it. "Wrong syntax near 'IF (NEW.retirado = 1) THEN
        UPDATE recolectores
        SET recolectores' en la linea 3"

Answer (score 1):

You have need a `DELIMITER and the syntax is off

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER NumAvisosRecolectados_AU #after update
AFTER UPDATE ON avisos.retirado 
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    IF (NEW.retirado = 1) THEN
        UPDATE recolectores
        SET recolectores.num_avisos_recolectados = recolectores.num_avisos_recolectados + 1
        WHERE idRecolector  = NEW.idAvisos;
    END IF;
END//
DELIMITER ;
```

New edit

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER NumAvisosRecolectados_AU #after update
AFTER UPDATE ON avisos
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    IF (NEW.retirado = 1) THEN

            UPDATE recolectores
            SET recolectores.num_avisos_recolectados = recolectores.num_avisos_recolectados + 1
            WHERE reservas.FK_IDavisos = avisos.ID_avisos
            AND reservas.FK_IDrecolector = recolectores.ID_recolector;
    END IF;
END; //
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: 1) `avisos.retirado` is a column (see sample) 2) *after i update the table avisos to **set "retirado" to true** (1)* - i.e. `OLD.retirado` must be checked too. 3) `retirado` check may be integrated into WHERE - we'll obtain single-statement trigger not needed in BEGIN-END and delimiter reassingning.

Comment: @nbk I made an update, i changed some things that you suggested, but i'm still getting a syntax error, i've tried taking off the " ; " and putting then back on other places, but still getting errors

Comment: i updated my answer, with your new code, see what i changed. Every command has to hasto end with a selicolon, you don't need another begin  and e3nd, but when you use them the end has also to have a selicolon

Answer (score 0):

Here the trigger is before updating a column in a directed table :

```
 DELIMETER $$
    
    CREATE TRIGGER update_trigger BEFORE UPDATE ON your_table_name 
    FOR EACH ROW
    
    BEGIN
    
    IF NEW.value <> 0 THEN 
    
    UPDATE table_name SET col_name = NEW.value WHERE col_id = NEW.id
    
    END IF;
    
    END ;

DELEMITER ;
```

Execute the query and everything will be fine , **That's it!!**